# check null value before sorting using lambda expression

Tags: lambda, java-8

I want to sort the menuList by parentId using lambda expression, parentId can be null. i tried below code but i am not able to find the way to add nullcheck for parentId, because of which i am getting nullpointer exception.

```
List<MenuList> menuList = session.createQuery("from MenuList").list();
menuList.sort((p1, p2) ->
p1.getParentId().compareTo(p2.getParentId()));
```

could you help me in adding nullcheck for parentId.
Note: I don't want to skip the menu having parentId null.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the factory methods in Comparator:

```
menuList.sort(Comparator.comparing(MenuList::getParentId, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```