# Java: rewrite comparator to Lambda - nullsafe

Tags: java, lambda, comparison

How can i rewrite this:

```
private Comparator<Domain> byRank;

...

byRank = new Comparator<Domain>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Domain d1, Domain d2) {
    float tmp1 = d1.getDomainRank() == null ? 0 : d1.getDomainRank();
    float tmp2 = d2.getDomainRank() == null ? 0 : d2.getDomainRank();
    return Float.compare(tmp1, tmp2);
  }
};
```

into lambda?

According to [check null value before sorting using lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32658528/check-null-value-before-sorting-using-lambda-expression), I tried this:

```
byRank = Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(Domain::getDomainRank));
```

However, it fails with:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$77a9974f$1(Comparator.java:469)
    at java.util.Comparators$NullComparator.compare(Comparators.java:83)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUpUsingComparator(PriorityQueue.java:669)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUp(PriorityQueue.java:645)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.offer(PriorityQueue.java:344)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.add(PriorityQueue.java:321)
```

**Edit**: the lambda fails even if I check compared objects for null before comparison:

```
Queue<Domain> topByRank = new PriorityQueue<>(TOP, byRank);

...

for (Domain domain : domains) {
  if (domain == null) { // check here
    continue;
  }
  topByRank.add(domain); // here it fails
}
```

Comment: For what I see d1 or d2 should be null

Comment: @freedev I check for null object (see edit). And the non-lambda version works without failing. Wouldn't it fail on d1.getDomainRank() or d2.getDomainRank() too?

Comment: Comparator.comparing is throwing the NPE. You have to turn the calls around. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28500970/982149

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will put null `Domain`s first. If you want to check for null *rank*, you need to use this:

```
Comparator.comparing(Domain::getDomainRank, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
```

But keep in mind that this is only equivalent to your original comparator if the rank can't be less than 0. Otherwise, you'll have to test a similar expression:

```
Comparator.comparing(d -> d.getDomainRank() == null ? 0 : d.getDomainRank())
```

Alternatively, you might have meant to use `Float.MIN_VALUE` instead of 0 in your original code.

Comment: Thats it, and thank you for that warning about zero boundary.

Answer (score 5):

It should be:

```
Comparator.comparing(Domain::getDomainRank,
           Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
```

So we sort a list based on `domainRank`. But what are we going to do with `Domain` objects whose `domainRank` value is null? We going to keep them at the head of our collection:
`Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())`